# Fixed layout height with scrollable in Twitter bootstrap 3.2.0

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am developing a design layout using bootstrap 3.2.0. I have Fixed header and footer. and I am now trying to have one container full-height with independent scrollbars. Is there any good way to do this with twitter bootstrap?

Here is a picture of the layout I am trying to build.

[image]

and sample code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="author" content="" />
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.2.0" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </form>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12"> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur molestie pharetra lacus, a tincidunt elit fermentum ac. Praesent ac mauris nisl. Cras aliquet imperdiet nunc, vestibulum faucibus urna laoreet eu. Aliquam pharetra leo ut mauris tempus dignissim. Aenean mollis dui sed orci hendrerit vitae hendrerit nisi convallis. Ut id libero a metus ullamcorper consectetur. Suspendisse sed risus erat. In pharetra velit condimentum nisl interdum sed iaculis mi consectetur. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Maecenas vulputate consectetur urna, a dignissim odio vestibulum a.</p>
<p>Aliquam pharetra, nunc a tempor sodales, orci sem pretium orci, quis pretium tellus purus ac nunc. Morbi dignissim urna eget sapien laoreet volutpat. Sed lacus lorem, vulputate eu aliquet non, egestas vel augue. Fusce gravida arcu at elit pharetra luctus. Curabitur pretium mi vitae purus posuere lobortis. Fusce pulvinar, mi at eleifend venenatis, magna risus rhoncus ipsum, dapibus ornare nisi risus ac lorem. Etiam feugiat felis eu nulla pretium pellentesque. Curabitur id lorem ut orci blandit commodo. Vestibulum tempor ultricies nibh, eu malesuada nibh commodo non. Morbi malesuada porta fringilla. Mauris suscipit vestibulum ante ut laoreet. Duis eget mollis tortor. In imperdiet tempus mauris eu hendrerit. Vivamus ultrices rutrum magna sit amet dapibus. Phasellus sem justo, pulvinar vitae adipiscing ut, dictum in tellus.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur molestie pharetra lacus, a tincidunt elit fermentum ac. Praesent ac mauris nisl. Cras aliquet imperdiet nunc, vestibulum faucibus urna laoreet eu. Aliquam pharetra leo ut mauris tempus dignissim. Aenean mollis dui sed orci hendrerit vitae hendrerit nisi convallis. Ut id libero a metus ullamcorper consectetur. Suspendisse sed risus erat. In pharetra velit condimentum nisl interdum sed iaculis mi consectetur. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Maecenas vulputate consectetur urna, a dignissim odio vestibulum a.</p>
<p>Aliquam pharetra, nunc a tempor sodales, orci sem pretium orci, quis pretium tellus purus ac nunc. Morbi dignissim urna eget sapien laoreet volutpat. Sed lacus lorem, vulputate eu aliquet non, egestas vel augue. Fusce gravida arcu at elit pharetra luctus. Curabitur pretium mi vitae purus posuere lobortis. Fusce pulvinar, mi at eleifend venenatis, magna risus rhoncus ipsum, dapibus ornare nisi risus ac lorem. Etiam feugiat felis eu nulla pretium pellentesque. Curabitur id lorem ut orci blandit commodo. Vestibulum tempor ultricies nibh, eu malesuada nibh commodo non. Morbi malesuada porta fringilla. Mauris suscipit vestibulum ante ut laoreet. Duis eget mollis tortor. In imperdiet tempus mauris eu hendrerit. Vivamus ultrices rutrum magna sit amet dapibus. Phasellus sem justo, pulvinar vitae adipiscing ut, dictum in tellus.</p></div>           
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
footer {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1030;
  height: 26px;
  background: #5f5f5f;
  bottom: 0;
  clear: both;
}
.container-fluid {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.col-md-12 {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100%;
}
```

and [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yzSPnQ19jRo3Q81wMUo1?p=preview)

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: @DanielA.White, see the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/yzSPnQ19jRo3Q81wMUo1?p=preview

Comment: please post it directly in the question.

Comment: Hi @DanielA.White, please out negative vote.

Comment: so what's the problem w/ that code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63303/discussion-between-shohel-and-daniel-a-white).

Comment: @DanielA.White, now see the full example in plunker

Comment: @DanielA.White, scroll bar is not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward.  The basic steps are:

1. Give the html and body elements 100% height
2. Fix your header and footer to the viewport using fixed positioning
3. Give the body element padding on the top equal to the height of your header and padding on the bottom equal to the height of your footer
4. Create a wrapping element for the scrollable content in the center and set its height to 100% and overflow property to auto.
5. Optionally, give the wrapping element a little padding on top and bottom to pull the content away from the header and footer at the top- and bottom-most scroll positions.

## [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/JnjRoRb1VcObwHNF9331?p=preview)

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  padding: 50px 0; /*Assumes that the header & footer are 50px*/
}
.main {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
   <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
           <!-- Navbar Here -->
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section class="main">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Main Content Here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <footer class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
      <!-- Footer Content Here -->
    </footer>
```

In the demo, I used the built in **navbar-fixed-top** and **nav-fixed-bottom** classes for the header and footer for convenience rather than create my own styles for positioning the header/footer.

Comment: Hi, Your answer is very good but I need scroll bar will be always visible and full height column of that screen. I have already mention my picture.

Comment: By using overflow-y: scroll, scroll bar is visible but i can not set full height column.

Comment: I don't see the issue you described.  The demo is updated.  Can you check it?  Two possible causes: it's a browser-specific issue, or it's a conflict with some other CSS on your page.  If the demo works for you, it's likely the latter.  If that's the case, you can post your actual code in your plunker and I'll take a look for you.

Comment: Remove <p></p> content except one and set .col-xs-12 {
    background-color: gray;
}, then you will see the column not full height.

Comment: without set padding: 50px 0; into body, no need set 50px, because header will be load pragmatically and header height will be according to header content

Comment: Ok, you have given me right answer according to my problem thanks.